# Fixed footer overlap content

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and I am trying to have a footer at the bottom of the page. I am using class="fixed-bottom". Problem is when I have a lot of content footer is overlapping content. I have layout like this:

```
<body>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="page-loader" style="display: none;">
        <div class="page-loader__spinner">
            <svg viewBox="25 25 50 50">
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"></circle>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
    <header class="header">          
    </header>  
    <section class="content">

            <footer class="footer fixed-bottom">
                <div class="footerProfil hidden-lg-up">
                    <p>
                        content
                    </p>
                </div>

            </footer>
    </section>
   </main>
</body>
```

This is my CSS

```
body, html {
  background-color: #fafafa !important;
}
body {
   font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif!important;
   font-size: 1rem;
   font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
   color: #707070;
 }

.footer {
  text-align: center;
   padding-top: 4rem;
   padding-right: 1rem;
   padding-bottom: 3rem;
   padding-left: 1rem;
  }

.fixed-bottom {
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
}
  .content:not(.content--boxed):not(.content--full) {
     padding: 102px 30px 400px 300px;
 }
 .fixed-bottom, .fixed-top {
   position: fixed;
   right: 0;
   z-index: 1030;
 }
```

Can anybody help me with this? Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `padding-bottom: XXpx` to `.content` class, where xx - is the footer height

Comment: I added 400px and still overlap content.

Comment: Thank you for the link, as you can see footer overlap content, Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: I'm not seeing the overlapping footer in the example (it answers the question correctly). That is the common fix I've seen. Getting the height of the footer with jQuery and setting the padding-bottom to the number of the footer height will work best dynamically and works best responsively.

Comment: @jomskris it's a normal behaviour. Could you show an example what you expect to receive?

Comment: @Satif ideal would be like this: https://jsfiddle.net/StartBootstrap/out2g1mq/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=out2g1mq So no meter how much content you have footer never overlap the content. Here is an image:  https://ibb.co/pzZshWv

Comment: @jomskris but as I saw in your example, it's not fixed https://jsfiddle.net/h1twL3ru/1/

Comment: just remove position: fixed; and that's it

Comment: @Satif The example with Bootstrap's flex (https://jsfiddle.net/h1twL3ru/1/) works because the page automatically is the full height of the browser window so the footer is pushed to be below that.